# How to directly add user to muc room in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

How to directly add user to muc room in ejabberd without send invites.
Add user to muc room is done only by admin. Is their any method for using ejabberd rest api.
Please suggest.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help - **set_room_affiliation**

https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#set-room-affiliation